# PHP error: cannot redeclare class

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class dept_officer extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
     {
         parent::__construct();
     }

     function get_sponsorship_list()
     {
         $this->db->from('tbl_donor');
         $this->db->join('tbl_sponsorship', 'tbl_donor.DonorId = tbl_sponsor.DonorId');
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result(); 
     }

    function get_programme_list()
     {
         $this->db->from('tbl_program');
         $this->db->join('tbl_sponsorship', 'tbl_program.SponsorshipId = tbl_sponsor.ponsorshipId');
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result(); 
     }

    function get_child_list()
     {
         $this->db->from('tbl_child');
         $this->db->join('tbl_family', 'tbl_child.FamilyID = tbl_family.FamilyID');
         $this->db->join('tbl_school', 'tbl_child.SchoolID = tbl_school.SchoolID');
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result(); 
     }

    function get_crpo_list()
     {
         $this->db->from('tbl_crpo');
         $this->db->join('tbl_district', 'tbl_ds_division.DistrictI = tbl_district.DistrictId'); 
         $this->db->join('tbl_dsdivision', 'tbl_crpo.ds_divisionId = tbl_ds_division.ds_divisionId');
         $query = $this->db->get();
         return $query->result(); 
     }
}

?>
```

I've created this class to contains all the queries to display list of different users in the system. i get a compile error saying cannot redeclare class dept_officer even though i haven't tried to declare any classes.
The above is the code for the model in codeigniter

Comment: try to rename your class, maybe theres already a class that use that name

Comment: Is it possible that you've included your PHP file twice? To avoid double inclusion, you should use `include_once` instead of `include`.

Comment: Please note in CodeIgniter 3 naming system for Model, Library, Controller class name first letter should be capitalize

Comment: Which CI version you use???